# How to display UISearchbar on pulling a table view or a view

Tags: ios7, tableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to load a view simply with a tableview. And when i pull the rows down i need to

display a search bar on top of first cell of table view. Every time this search bar should

appear only on pulling down the table view.

I tried this code in viewDidAppear: but it dint worked for me.

self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, SEARCH_BAR_HEIGHT);

Comment: If you're using InterfaceBuilder and just add a `UISearchBar` as subview to the `UITableView` everything should work out of the box.

Comment: @Daniel i am using storyboard